# Can someone help me to understand, why this code does not converge?

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm studying RL from the following [book](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-reinforcement-learning-in-action), which is very well written but the code written along the book does not work as expected.

In my case I'm trying to implement an Actor-Critic RL algorithm to "solve" the [cartpole](https://gymnasium.farama.org/v0.28.1/environments/classic_control/cart_pole/) problem in Gymnasium.
The code I wrote is 1:1 the code from the [gitlab repository](https://github.com/DeepReinforcementLearning/DeepReinforcementLearningInAction/blob/master/Chapter%205/Ch5_book.ipynb) accompanying the book which is maintained by the authors themselves, apart the change in this line:

```
state_, _, done, info = worker_env.step(action.detach().numpy())
```

in

```
state_, _, done, _, info = worker_env.step(action.detach().numpy())
```

since the last version of Gymnasium adds the truncation value to the returned values.

Here the code:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch import optim
import numpy as np
from torch.nn import functional as F
import gymnasium as gym
import torch.multiprocessing as mp #A

class ActorCritic(nn.Module): #B
    def __init__(self):
        super(ActorCritic, self).__init__()
        self.l1 = nn.Linear(4,25)
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(25,50)
        self.actor_lin1 = nn.Linear(50,2)
        self.l3 = nn.Linear(50,25)
        self.critic_lin1 = nn.Linear(25,1)
    def forward(self,x):
        x = F.normalize(x,dim=0)
        y = F.relu(self.l1(x))
        y = F.relu(self.l2(y))
        actor = F.log_softmax(self.actor_lin1(y),dim=0) #C
        c = F.relu(self.l3(y.detach()))
        critic = torch.tanh(self.critic_lin1(c)) #D
        return actor, critic #E

def worker(t, worker_model, counter, params):
    worker_env = gym.make("CartPole-v1")
    worker_env.reset()
    worker_opt = optim.Adam(lr=1e-4,params=worker_model.parameters()) #A
    worker_opt.zero_grad()
    for i in range(params['epochs']):
        worker_opt.zero_grad()
        values, logprobs, rewards = run_episode(worker_env,worker_model) #B 
        actor_loss,critic_loss,eplen = update_params(worker_opt,values,logprobs,rewards) #C
        counter.value = counter.value + 1 #D

        print(f"Episode: {i}, Eplen: {eplen}")

def run_episode(worker_env, worker_model):
    state = torch.from_numpy(worker_env.env.state).float() #A
    values, logprobs, rewards = [],[],[] #B
    done = False
    j=0
    while (done == False): #C
        j+=1
        policy, value = worker_model(state) #D
        values.append(value)
        logits = policy.view(-1)
        action_dist = torch.distributions.Categorical(logits=logits)
        action = action_dist.sample() #E
        logprob_ = policy.view(-1)[action]
        logprobs.append(logprob_)
        state_, _, done, _, info = worker_env.step(action.detach().numpy())
        state = torch.from_numpy(state_).float()
        if done: #F
            reward = -10
            worker_env.reset()
        else:
            reward = 1.0
        rewards.append(reward)
    return values, logprobs, rewards

def update_params(worker_opt,values,logprobs,rewards,clc=0.1,gamma=0.95):
        rewards = torch.Tensor(rewards).flip(dims=(0,)).view(-1) #A
        logprobs = torch.stack(logprobs).flip(dims=(0,)).view(-1)
        values = torch.stack(values).flip(dims=(0,)).view(-1)
        Returns = []
        ret_ = torch.Tensor([0])
        for r in range(rewards.shape[0]): #B
            ret_ = rewards[r] + gamma * ret_
            Returns.append(ret_)
        Returns = torch.stack(Returns).view(-1)
        Returns = F.normalize(Returns,dim=0)
        actor_loss = -1*logprobs * (Returns - values.detach()) #C
        critic_loss = torch.pow(values - Returns,2) #D
        loss = actor_loss.sum() + clc*critic_loss.sum() #E
        loss.backward()
        worker_opt.step()
        return actor_loss, critic_loss, len(rewards)

MasterNode = ActorCritic() #A
MasterNode.share_memory() #B
processes = [] #C
params = {
    'epochs':1000,
    'n_workers':12,
}
counter = mp.Value('i',0) #D
for i in range(params['n_workers']):
    p = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(i,MasterNode,counter,params)) #E
    p.start() 
    processes.append(p)
for p in processes: #F
    p.join()
for p in processes: #G
    p.terminate()
    
print(counter.value,processes[1].exitcode) #H
```

For reasons that I still do not understand, the code does not converge to a stable solution. The code runs until the end but the reward "levels" in a very spread range between 150 and 300. This result is far away from, what other tutorials online show in their results.

So my question is:

1. Since the code seems to reflect the formula behind actor-critic algorithms, there is a specific reason, why it does not converge? I tried even changing the hyperparameters: gamma and the learning rate. I even changed the number hidden neurons in the Actor2Critic class to 64 and 128. But it gets even worse.
2. One difference from other algorithms out there is the `tanh` function at the end of the critic layer. I removed it and nothing changed. The algorithm does not converge at all.
   Usually do you use that function to clamp the output value of a layer between -1 and 1?